# AWS Glue Studio -Jupyter External Libraries

Tags: python, aws-glue

I have trouble adding external libraries to Jupyter Notebook.

For example, I downloaded pg8000 zip file or whl file.

I set the parameters in the configure section below:

```
"extra_py_files": "s3://Library/pg.zip",
"additional_python_modules": "pg8000"
```

However, pg8000 is not found :(